# How can I store an array in my.settings in vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, my.settings

I am trying to store a user input array in a my.settings variable in vb.net.  I would like for the user to enter an array in the form {1,2,3}, store that as a string in the setting and then be able to use the setting value later to create a new array.  The code will be something like:

```
Dim inputarray()
Dim outputarray()

inputarray=textbox1.text
my.settings.inputstoredarray.add(inputarray)

outputarray=my.settings.inputstoredarray
textbox2.text=outputarray(0)

'If the user types "{1,2,3}' in textbox1, textbox2 should show "1"
```

I have tried multiple versions of this but there seem to always be type conversion errors.  I don't understand why it works if I hardcode:

```
inputarray={1,2,3}
```

and yet the below code does not work:

```
inputarray=my.settings.inputstoredarray
```

How can I store a user provided array in my.settings and retrieve it for use later?

does not work even if I go into settings and set the string value for the setting to {1,2,3}

Comment: A string is not an array.  You get a string back from `textbox1.text`...

Comment: I understand but I can define an array using the string "{1,2,3}" so why can't I use a stored string to do the same?

Comment: How are you defining an array with the string "{1,2,3}"?....

Comment: Array()={1,2,3} works fine.

Comment: Right, but that is still not a STRING as to just claimed it was...

Comment: Perhaps in the scope of the app that is true but I would think there would be a way to store it as a string like:  stingarr="{1,2,3}" and then define the array as arr=stringarr.  I hope that there is but that is basically my question.

Comment: Sure.  You want to `String.Split()` to get a string array. Look up examples on how to convert a string array to an integer array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up your setting in Project Properties, Settings tab as follows.
[image]

Then save the setting as follows.

```
Private Sub SaveStringToSettings()
    My.Settings.StringOfInts = TextBox1.Text 'User types in {1, 2, 3}
End Sub
```

To retrieve the setting and turn it into an array

```
Private Sub CreateArrayFromSettings()
    Dim SettingValue = My.Settings.StringOfInts
    Debug.Print(SettingValue) 'View this in the Immediate window
    'Get rid of the braces
    Dim TrimmedString = SettingValue.Trim({"{"c, "}"c})
    'Split the string by the commas into an array 
    Dim Splits = TrimmedString.Split(","c)
    'Get rid of the spaces
    For i = 0 To Splits.Length - 1
        Splits(i) = Splits(i).Trim
    Next
    TextBox1.Text = Splits(0) 'Displays 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't store an array in application settings. What you can do is create a setting of type `StringCollection`. You can then use it as a `StringCollection` in code or you can transfer the data back and forth between the `StringCollection` and an array if you really need an array.

Start by opening the *Settings* page of the project properties and creating a new setting of type `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection`. For this example, I'll name it `MyStringCollection` but you should name it appropriately for your app. When you do this, notice that the `Value` field is empty by default. This means that the setting is `Nothing` by default. That's OK but it means that you need to actually create the collection object in code before using it for the first time, e.g.

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If My.Settings.MyStringCollection Is Nothing Then
        My.Settings.MyStringCollection = New StringCollection
    End If

    'Use My.Settings.MyStringCollection here.
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you can force the settings UI to create the object for you. To do that, select the `Value` field for that setting and click the browse (...) button. Add any arbitrary character and click the *OK* button. Notice that the `Value` field is populated with an XML snippet that contains the text you entered. Click the browse (...) button again, delete the text and click *OK* again. Notice that the XML remains, even though the text you had entered is removed. That XML will now create the `StringCollection` object automatically, so you don't need code to do so.

If you're happy wiith a collection of `String` values then you can use the setting directly in code wherever you like. It works, for the most part, like a `List(Of String)`, allowing you to add and remove items at will. If you specifically need an array or you need a type other than `String` then you will have to do some translation, e.g.

```vb
'Load the collection items into a String array.
Dim myStringArray = My.Settings.MyStringCollection.Cast(Of String)().ToArray()

'Load the collection items into an Integer array.
Dim myIntegerArray = My.Settings.MyStringCollection.Cast(Of String)().Select(Function(s) CInt(s)).ToArray()

'Repopulate the collection from a String array.
My.Settings.MyStringCollection.Clear()
My.Settings.MyStringCollection.AddRange(myStringArray)

'Repopulate the collection from an Integer array.
My.Settings.MyStringCollection.Clear()
My.Settings.MyStringCollection.AddRange(myIntegerArray.Select(Function(n) n.ToString()).ToArray())
```

If you want to display the contents of your collection in a `TextBox` than you might do something like this:

```vb
TextBox1.Text = String.Join(",", My.Settings.MyStringCollection.Cast(Of String)())
```

That will create a single, comma-delimited `String` containing all the items. To repopulate the collection from a `TextBox` containing such text, do this:

```vb
My.Settings.MyStringCollection.Clear()
My.Settings.MyStringCollection.AddRange(TextBox1.Text.Split(","c))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can browse for additional setting types in your *Project properties/Settings* tab but you'll find it fairly limited with the most common message being that you can't use that type. Array is one you can't use, I'm afraid.

But you *can* use the fully-supported `StringCollection`:

```
Dim saveTest As New StringCollection() From {"1", "2", "3", "4"}
My.Settings.MySetting = saveTest
My.Settings.Save()
Dim loadTest As StringCollection = My.Settings.MySetting
```

Another option would be to use, say, and XML or JSON string that you de-serialize but that's getting a bit involved.